# how to capture and decrypt packets sent over TLS

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, fiddler

I have been using MITM for decrypting https traffic , using tools like fiddler and burpsuite . Is there a way to decrypt packet sent over TLS, any guidance would be a real help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but I can't find the post right now. The tl;dr is that you will need the TLS master key, which means you will need have complete control over at least one of the two endpoints.

Comment: I surely searched from the questions , if you find it letme know , otherwise dont mark it duplicate, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Capture**

1. --> Open Fiddler
2. --> Tools
3. --> Fiddler Options
4. Set the option boxes as shown in the image below:

[image: Fiddler: Capture HTTPS instructions]

Source: [How do I use Fiddler to capture HTTP/HTTPS sessions for debugging?](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/user-experience/troubleshooting/how-do-i-use-fiddler-to-capture-https-sessions-for-debugging/)

**Decrypt**

If you haven't already, enable the *Decrypt HTTPS traffic* option, shown in the image above. You can read *how* to decrypt TLS traffic with Fiddler in the [How come I can see full HTTPS requests via Fiddler?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180830/how-come-i-can-see-a-full-https-requests-via-fiddler/180834#180834) thread, which links to a set of [instructions](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp).

Comment: but this shows the data for https traffic not TLS , as for tls fiddler outputs tunnel to 443